# Reset/delete post views meta/custom field after X hours or minutes or seconds

Tags: post-meta, wp-cron

There's lots of snippets and plugins that will count post views but I'm trying to find a way a way to reset the number of views back to zero after X hours(or minutes or seconds or whatevaaaa).

I'm assuming i'd need incorporate [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_post_meta) `<?php delete_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value); ?>`

Here is [the snippet](http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/cache/track-post-views-without-a-plugin-using-post-meta/) I'm using...

```
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}
// Remove issues with prefetching adding extra views
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
```

Would this cron work?

```
<?php 
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_task_hook' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'my_task_hook' );
}

add_action( 'my_task_hook', 'my_task_function' );

function my_task_function() {
  delete_post_meta($post_id, 'post_views_count', true);
}
?>
```

Comment: Set up a wp_cron job to delete the meta values

Comment: @PieterGoosen see my code addition

Answer (score 2):

Your code for scheduling event isn't correct, here is the correct one:

```
function hits_set_zero_schedule() {
  if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'hits_set_to_zero') )
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'hits_set_zero' );
}
add_action( 'wp', 'hits_set_zero_schedule' );

function hits_set_zero_func() {
  delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_views_count', true );
}
add_action( 'hits_set_zero', 'hits_set_zero_func' );
```

Also, you can define intervals otherwise than `daily` by adding a little snippet to your code:

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'my_custom_schedule' );
function my_custom_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules[ 'five_minutes' ] = array(
        'interval'          =>  5 * 60,
        'display'           =>  'Once five minutes'
    );

    return $schedules;
}
```

You can change the `interval` element in the `$schedules` element, it's in seconds.

Comment: Thanks, "you can define intervals otherwise than daily by adding a little snippet to your **code**".. what **code** are we talking about?

Comment: @Pete functions.php or one of your plugin files.

Comment: I'm just trying to get my head around how your second snippet works with the first snippet?. The first snippet resets daily, but why can't we just change the 'daily' to 'hourly' etc or at least incorporate the second snippet into the first snippet rather than having 2 separate snippets? I think i'm missing something?